# Mobile chess app that allows take backs?

Tags: ios, chess

My dad and I use Chess.com to play each other on our phones, but I feel bad because I've beat him the past 200 games and he wishes that I could give him take backs.

I know that there are chess programs / web apps like ICC which allow take backs, but is there a mobile app that does?

We both use iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chess.com site allows "take back", *if your opponent agrees*, in unrated games **only** & they have an iPhone [app](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=329218549&mt=8) for both free and premium members but I have to say that I have not tried it as I do not have an iPhone so do not know for sure if that feature is available in the app.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this works on the app but we can use the mobile site instead.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lichess](https://lichess.org/) app/website allows players to request takebacks. It's also generally a good chess site. (Also, at least on Android, the mobile app is way better than Chess.com's IMO, but I'm biased.)

The official iOS download link: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lichess-free-online-chess/id968371784